# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
>   -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Portuguese Language breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          5
Users destroyed                                   1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue             9         94
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          9         70
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                6         71
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1        185
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                0         45
Tags merged                                       2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             4          0
Tag synonyms created                              4          0
Questions reopened                                3          0
Questions protected                               1          1
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0         28
Questions closed                                 13         10
Question flags handled⁴                          11         17
Posts unlocked                                    0          3
Posts undeleted                                   0          5
Posts locked                                      0          8
Posts deleted⁵                                   50         31
Posts bumped                                      0         70
Comments flagged                                  0         26
Comments deleted⁶                                48        102
Comment flags handled                            15         11
Answers flagged                                   2         97
Answer flags handled                             87         12
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

---

### Portuguese Version

Uma característica distinta dos sites da rede Stack Exchange é a forma como estes são moderados:

> A rede Stack Exchange foi desenhada para ser auto-regulada, de modo que o custo de moderação do sistema é amortizado em milhares de pequenas porções de esforço diário dos usuários regulares.
>   -- [*A Theory of Moderation*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Embora existam [Moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), uma parte significativa da *moderação* é feita por pessoas comuns, usando os privilégios obtidos através das suas contribuições ao site. Cada um de vocês contribui com um pouco do seu tempo e esforço, e juntos todos conseguem realizar muita coisa.

Ao entrar em um novo ano, vamos fazer uma pausa e refletir, e por um momento apreciar o trabalho que todos fizemos juntos. Para isso, vejamos como foi feita a moderação no Portuguese Language, dividido por atividade, nos últimos 12 meses:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  0          5
Users destroyed                                   1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue             9         94
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue          9         70
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                6         71
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 1        185
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                0         45
Tags merged                                       2          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             4          0
Tag synonyms created                              4          0
Questions reopened                                3          0
Questions protected                               1          1
Questions migrated                                4          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0         28
Questions closed                                 13         10
Question flags handled⁴                          11         17
Posts unlocked                                    0          3
Posts undeleted                                   0          5
Posts locked                                      0          8
Posts deleted⁵                                   50         31
Posts bumped                                      0         70
Comments flagged                                  0         26
Comments deleted⁶                                48        102
Comment flags handled                            15         11
Answers flagged                                   2         97
Answer flags handled                             87         12
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0
```

#### Observações

¹ "Comunidade" se refere tanto a [membros do Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users) *sem* [o diamante próximo ao seus nomes](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), e ao sistema automático conhecido como [user #-1](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² O sistema suspende um utilizador em três circunstâncias: quando o utilizador é recriado depois de ser suspenso anteriormente, quando é recriado depois de ser destruído por *spam* ou abuso, ou quando a conta sofre uma suspensão em toda a rede.

³ Inclui todas as revisões que não foram ignoradas - ou seja, as duas revisões necessárias para as Edições Sugeridas contam como 2, pois o objetivo é indicar a frequência das ações de moderação. O mesmo se aplica a sinalizações, etc.

⁴ Inclui sinalizações para fechar (mas *não* os votos para fechar ou reabrir).

⁵ Ignora os inúmeros casos em que a publicação é apagada automaticamente em resposta a alguma ação.

⁶ Inclui comentários apagados pelos próprios autores (que também considera algumas sinalizações de comentários que foram tratadas).

Desejando a todos um Feliz Ano Novo...

---

Obrigado ao [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) do [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com) pela tradução. Optei por não traduzir o quadro visto que as ações dos site estão em inglês.